# Get the local path of streamed video

Tags: video-streaming, video-download

I watch movies online (not on YouTube). As my internet speed is slow (512 kbps), I watch the movie while streaming instead of downloading and then watching. I have seen that I can move the seek bar to any position in the vicinity of streamed video. So, I am assuming that the streamed video will be stored on local drive somewhere in a temporary folder.

I would like to know that path so that I can copy the video file and store in my movies folder. My default browser is Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the video streaming site the data is most likely automatically being stored in your browsers cache. Usually this data is not easily accessible nor is it easy to piece together.

I highly suggest taking a look at a program such as [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) which will find the video sources on pages and allow you to download them in various qualities. Therefore you could avoid the streaming aspect and just download the video by copying the link and using JDownloader. I mean you're downloading the video anyway from the site when viewing it, so might as well have a copy of it.